# How to connect Oracle with GCP Data Fusion

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I wanna connect my oracle db with GCP Data Fusion but I don't it. I couldn't find jar file. I have a table in Oracle and get data to BQ so I don't know what I will use. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

This page describes how to connect to use JDBC to read data from your database in Data Fusion pipelines - https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/using-jdbc-drivers.

See [here](https://rspraneethkumar.medium.com/oracle-to-bigquery-create-a-pipeline-to-extract-data-from-oracle-and-load-it-to-bq-using-data-69ac855f473f) for instructions to create an Oracle->BQ batch pipeline.

If you want to continuously replicate changed data from an Oracle database to a BigQuery, you can do so using Data Fusion Replication. See https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/oracle-to-bigquery